# plinq on large lists taking enormous time

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, plinq

I have two in memory lists plays and consumers one having 15 mil objects and the other around 3 mil.

the following are a few of queries i'm firing..

```
consumersn=consumers.AsParallel()
                    .Where(w => plays.Any(x => x.consumerid == w.consumerid))
                    .ToList();


List<string> consumerids = plays.AsParallel()
                                .Where(w => w.playyear == group_period.year 
                                         && w.playmonth == group_period.month 
                                         && w.sixteentile == group_period.group)
                                .Select(c => c.consumerid)
                                .ToList();


int groupcount = plays.AsParallel()
                      .Where(w => w.playyear == period.playyear 
                               && w.playmonth == period.playmonth 
                               && w.sixteentile == group 
                               && consumerids.Any(x => x == w.consumerid))
                      .Count();
```

I'm using 16 core machine with 32 GB RAM, inspite of this.. the first query took around 20 hours to run..

Am I doing something wrong..

All help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Profiler is your friend here. But it looks like you're doing 15M * 3M operations in your very first query here.

Answer (score 2):

The first LINQ query is very inefficient, parallelization can only help you so much.

Explanation: When you write `consumers.Where(w => plays.Any(x => x.consumerid == w.consumerid))`, it means that, for every object in `consumer`, you will potentially iterate over the whole `plays` list to find the affected consumers. So that is a maximum of 3 million consumers times 15 million plays = 45 trillion operations. Even across 16 cores, that is about 2.8 trillion operations per core.

So, the first step here would be to group all plays by their consumerIds, and to cache the result in an appropriate data structure:

```
var playsByConsumerIds = plays.ToLookup(x => x.consumerid, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Then, your first request becomes:

```
consumersn = consumers.Where(w => playsByConsumerIds.Contains(w.consumerid)).ToList();
```

This query should be much faster, even without any parallelization.

I cannot fix the following queries because I don't see exactly what you are doing exactly with `group_period`, but I would suggest using `GroupBy` or `ToLookup` to create all groups in a single pass.

Comment: Thanks.. I will read on ToLookup. As far as the other two queries are concerned.. they are happening inside a foreach loop and there is no groupby clause used there.. The only reason to get consumerids in second query is to be able to use it in third query. So will it be right to change .Select(c => c.consumerid)in second query to .ToLookup(x => x.consumerid, StringComparer.Ordinal); and consumerids.Any(x => x == w.consumerid) to consumerids.Contains(w.consumerid)

Comment: What I am suggesting is that you can probably use a `GroupBy` to avoid a loop for the second and third query.

Comment: Sorry, Unable to understand what you mean by using 'GroupBy' to avoid a loop.. could you please provide an example..The where clauses in the second and third query use values coming from different sources-group_period and (period and group) respectively..

Answer (score 1):

The first query took 20 hours to run because `plays.Any(x => x.consumerid == w.consumerid)` needs to walk through the entire list of 15,000,000 plays each time the `consumerid` is not there.

You can speed this up by constructing a hash set of all consumer IDs in `plays`, like this:

```
var consumerIdsInPlays = new HashSet<string>(plays.Select(p => p.consumerid));
```

Now your first query can be rewritten for an O(1) lookup:

```
consumersn=consumers
    .AsParallel()
    .Where(w => consumerIdsInPlays.Contains(w.consumerid))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: can I use Hashset for the second query and will it be faster?? Also should I change consumerids.Any(x => x == w.consumerid) to consumerids.Contains( w.consumerid) in the third query. will that be faster?? Tx

Comment: @Arnab Second query does not search lists, so it wouldn't be faster. Third query can be made faster if you turn `consumerids` to a hash set, and use `Contains` in place of `Any`. You can also replace `Where(cond).Count()` with `Count(cond)`.