# Adding rows from one IEnumerable to another based on conditions

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have two array..

```
var data1 = new[] { 
        new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2009, Sales = 1212 },
        new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2009, Sales = 522 },
        new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2010, Sales = 1337 },
        new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2011, Sales = 711 },
        new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2012, Sales = 2245 },
        new { Product = "Product 3", Year = 2012, Sales = 1000 }
    };

var data2 = new[] { 
        new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2009, Sales = 1212 },
        new { Product = "Product 1", Year = 2010, Sales = 1337 },
        new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2011, Sales = 711 },
        new { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2012, Sales = 2245 }
    };
```

What I want to do is check for each distinct `Product` and `Year` in `data2`, and if any row exists for any combination of such `Product` and `Year` in `data1` but not in `data2` then add that row to `data2`.

Example..
In `data2`, distinct products are `Product1` and `Product2` and distinct years are `Year1`, `Year2`, `Year3` and `Year4`.

In data1 there exists a row `{ Product = "Product 2", Year = 2009, Sales = 522 }`, which is not present in `data2`, so I wish to add it to `data2`.

What I can do is get distinct products and years in two variables.

Then do a for each loop in both and check if combination exists in data1 but not in data2 and if so add it to data2.

What I would like to get is a single LINQ query which can do this job for me rather than doing two distinct separately and then doing a couple of for each loop.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean _literally_ add it to the other array or you just want a _new_ collection that contains the items in `data2` AND certain items from `data1`?  The latter is easier since arrays are fixed-size.

Comment: I'm ok with the latter in fact that's better..

Comment: Also `{ Product = "Product 1", Year = 2009, Sales = 1212 }` exists in both arrays so I don't see why you say it needs to be added to `Data2`

Comment: sorry, I meant { Product = "Product 2", Year = 2009, Sales = 522 },editing question as well

Comment: You should use `Union` with a custom *Equality Comparer* but since you are using anonymous type the equality comparer is a bit different. So I think it would be better to search about implementing `IEqualityComparer` for anonymous type.

Comment: Are `(Year,Product)` combinations in `data1` unique? If not, how do I deal with duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work in a single query. However it is going to be sub-optimal, because for each item in `data1` you would need to check three conditions, which potentially require going through the entire `data2` for an O(m*n) time complexity (space complexity remains O(1), though).

You can avoid identical loop, though:

```
var uniqueProd = new HashSet<string>(data2.Select(d=>d.Product));
var uniqueYear = new HashSet<int>(data2.Select(d=>d.Year));
var knownPairs = new HashSet<Tuple<string,int>>(
    data2.Select(d=>Tuple.Create(d.Product, d.Year))
);
var newData2 = data2.Concat(
    data1.Where(d =>
        uniqueProd.Contains(d.Product)                       // The product is there
    &&  uniqueYear.Contains(d.Year)                          // The year is there
    && !knownPairs.Contains(Tuple.Create(d.Product, d.Year)) // Combination is not there
    )
).ToArray();
```

This solution is O(m+n) in time and also O(n) in space.

Comment: +1 for using ***HashSet***. I'm trying to understand HashSet. Could you please comment on different between yours and [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40182513/296861)? Thanks!

Comment: @Win Your solution will include year/product combinations from `data1` even for pairs not present in `data2`. Specifically, I think OP does not want the last row with `Product3`, because `Product3` is not among the products of `data2`.

Comment: I have never seen the use of Hashset prior to this. Is it fast compared to a List. I would appreciate if you could look at an old question of mine ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952453/plinq-on-large-lists-taking-enormous-time/ )and let me know if the Hashset usage would be useful there specially for the second and third queries, Tx

Answer (score 1):

I won't make any claims for efficiency, but it is possible in a single query.

If you are content to let Union handle removing duplicates, you can do:

```
var newd2 = data2.Union(
    from d1 in data1
    where
        (from d2p in data2 from d2y in data2 
         select new { d2p.Product, d2y.Year })
        .Distinct().Any(mp => mp.Product == d1.Product && mp.Year == d1.Year)
    select d1);
```

Alternatively, you can exclude pre-existing data2 matches and use `Concat`

```
var newd2 = data2.Concat(
    from d1 in data1
    where
        (from d2p in data2 from d2y in data2 select new { d2p.Product, d2y.Year })
        .Distinct().Any(mp => mp.Product == d1.Product && mp.Year == d1.Year) &&
        !data2.Any(mp => mp.Product == d1.Product && mp.Year == d1.Year)
    select d1
    );
```

OTOH, I couldn't resist some timings. If we call using Union as 1, using Concat varies from 73% of the time, creating HashSets uses 827% of the time and pulling the unique pair set out takes 54%, and skipping the .Distinct() takes 27%, though the dataset is too slow to tell differences in some of these.

Pulling out the pairs and dumping Distinct:

```
var newdd = (from d2p in data2 from d2y in data2 select new { d2p.Product, d2y.Year });
var newd2 = data2.Concat(
    from d1 in data1
    where
        newdd.Any(mp => mp.Product == d1.Product && mp.Year == d1.Year) &&
        !data2.Any(mp => mp.Product == d1.Product && mp.Year == d1.Year)
    select d1
    );
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how you got the timings info.. I would love to use the same on my data set..

Comment: I used LinqPad and the built-in Util.ElapsedTime to calculate timing for different queries. You can use the StopWatch class in general to time parts of your code, or use Visual Studio profiling.